# Android - org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, php, android, json

I'm trying to post the value from `sharedPreferences` to my PHP file. Here's the code of the activity:

```
public class ViewGradesActivity extends ListActivity {

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String url = "http://usamobileapp.pe.hu/webservice/viewGradesJSON.php";

// JSON Node name
private static final String TAG_GRADES = "grades";
private static final String TAG_SUBJECT = "subject";
private static final String TAG_PRELIM = "prelim";
private static final String TAG_MIDTERM = "midterm";
private static final String TAG_FINALS = "final";
private static final String TAG_AVERAGE = "average";
private static final String TAG_REMARKS = "remarks";

HttpPost httppost;
StringBuffer buffer;
HttpResponse response;
HttpClient httpclient;
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
ProgressDialog dialog = null;

// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray grades = null;

// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> gradesList;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_grades);

    gradesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    ListView lv = getListView();

    // Calling async task to get json
    new GetContacts().execute();
}

/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 * */
private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ViewGradesActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        String awesomeString = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ViewGradesActivity.this).getString("key", "");

        httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
        httppost= new HttpPost("http://usamobileapp.pe.hu/webservice/viewGradesJSON.php");

        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",awesomeString));
        try {
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Creating service handler class instance
        viewGrades_ServiceHandler sh = new viewGrades_ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, classSched_ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                grades = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_GRADES);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < grades.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = grades.getJSONObject(i);

                    String prelim = c.getString(TAG_PRELIM);
                    String subject = c.getString(TAG_SUBJECT);
                    String midterm = c.getString(TAG_MIDTERM);
                    String finals = c.getString(TAG_FINALS);
                    String ave = c.getString(TAG_AVERAGE);
                    String rem = c.getString(TAG_REMARKS);

                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> gradeDetails = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

                    gradeDetails.put(TAG_SUBJECT, subject);
                    gradeDetails.put(TAG_PRELIM, prelim);
                    gradeDetails.put(TAG_MIDTERM, midterm);
                    gradeDetails.put(TAG_FINALS, finals);
                    gradeDetails.put(TAG_AVERAGE, ave);
                    gradeDetails.put(TAG_REMARKS, rem);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    gradesList.add(gradeDetails);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                ViewGradesActivity.this, gradesList,
                R.layout.viewgrades_listitem, new String[] { TAG_SUBJECT, TAG_PRELIM,
                TAG_MIDTERM, TAG_FINALS, TAG_AVERAGE, TAG_REMARKS }, new int[] { R.id.name,
                R.id.email, R.id.mobile,  R.id.finals, R.id.average, R.id.remarks });

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

}

}
```

Then here's the part of the PHP where I used `$_POST`

```
$username= $_POST['username'];
$query_search = "select * from grades where rfid = '".$username."'";
$result = mysql_query("select * from grades where rfid = '".$username."'", $conn);
```

I'm wondering why whenever I tried to run the application and then when I get into this activity it doesn't display anything. And when I checked the Logcat the error mentioned above appears.

Thanks for the help.

EDIT: Here's the complete log I found in logcat:

```
03-23 22:07:54.009  23313-23354/com.example.kreshiathea.myfirstapp W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
03-23 22:07:54.015  23313-23354/com.example.kreshiathea.myfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
03-23 22:07:54.016  23313-23354/com.example.kreshiathea.myfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
03-23 22:07:54.016  23313-23354/com.example.kreshiathea.myfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
03-23 22:07:54.017  23313-23354/com.example.kreshiathea.myfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at com.example.kreshiathea.myfirstapp.ViewGradesActivity$GetContacts.doInBackground(ViewGradesActivity.java:147)
03-23 22:07:54.018  23313-23354/com.example.kreshiathea.myfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at com.example.kreshiathea.myfirstapp.ViewGradesActivity$GetContacts.doInBackground(ViewGradesActivity.java:101)
03-23 22:07:54.019  23313-23354/com.example.kreshiathea.myfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-23 22:07:54.020  23313-23354/com.example.kreshiathea.myfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-23 22:07:54.021  23313-23354/com.example.kreshiathea.myfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
03-23 22:07:54.022  23313-23354/com.example.kreshiathea.myfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-23 22:07:54.023  23313-23354/com.example.kreshiathea.myfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-23 22:07:54.024  23313-23354/com.example.kreshiathea.myfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
```